# How do I read a file and escape the characters?

Tags: ruby, file, escaping

I have a file that contains an array of strings like this:

```
["1234","4567","8899"]
```

I am opening the file like this:

```
File.open("./tmp/foo/foo_bar", "r") { |file| file.read }
```

but it comes back with quotations and `"\"` like this:

```
"[\"1234\",\"4567\",\"8899\"]"
```

How do I have the extra `""` and `"\"` removed?

Comment: How are you showing the data? using `p`?

Comment: You cannot have an array (directly) in a file. What you got is a string, and that is what you had in the file from the beginning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to de-serialize the file and turn the contents into a usable Ruby object, then in this case you can use the JSON library

```
require 'json'

contents = File.open("./tmp/foo/foo_bar", "r") { |file| file.read } # => "[\"1234\",\"4567\",\"8899\"]"
result = JSON.parse(contents) # => ["1234", "4567", "8899"]
result.is_a?(Array) # => true
```